# Pyspark : list of dictionaries to data frame

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe in which I have a column and each row contains a list of dictionaries :

```
[
Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'},{...}]"),
Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'},{...}]")
]
```

How can I parse it to a dataframe structure like this:

```
key1  | key2 | key3 | keyN |
value1|value2|value3|valueN|
value1|value2|value3|valueN|
```

Comment: You may have a look at [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) for your purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast string to ArrayType of dictionary (JSON) in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713790/how-to-cast-string-to-arraytype-of-dictionary-json-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row 
l = [Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]"), 
     Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]")]

# convert the list of Rows to an RDD: 
ll = sc.parallelize(l) 
df = sqlContext.read.json(ll.map(lambda r: dict(
                          kv for d in eval(r.payload) for kv in d.items())))
```

---

**Explanation:**

I guess the only ambiguity is in the following intermediate code:

```
dict(kv for d in eval(r.payload) for kv in d.items())
```

is used to convert from this format

```
[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]"
```

to this one:

```
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

---

output:

```
>>>df
DataFrame[key1: string, key2: string, key3: string]
>>> df.show() 
+------+------+------+
|  key1|  key2|  key3|
+------+------+------+
|value1|value2|value3|
|value1|value2|value3|
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: @TCreuillenet, Glad I was able to help :), consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Actually this result gives some columns that I'd to add to the original dataframe. What would be the best way ?

Comment: I'm amazed that both the question from the OP and the accepted answer were both given negative points from downvotes...

Comment: @devinbost: Stackoverflow should be more restricted with downvoters. There should be some kind of validation before downvote is accepted. Now it's only based on a rank of a user.

Answer (score -1):

To get expected dataframe structure:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import *

dataframe = [
Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]"),
Row(payload=u"[{'key1':'value4'},{'key2':'value5'},{'key3':'value6'}]")]

new_data = [eval(row['payload']) for row in dataframe]
# [[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}], [{'key1': 'value4'}, {'key2': 'value5'}, {'key3': 'value6'}]]

data_list = []
for sub_list in new_data:
    dict_list = {}
    for dict_val in sub_list:
        dict_list.update(dict_val)
    data_list.append(dict_list)
# [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, {'key1': 'value4', 'key2': 'value5', 'key3': 'value6'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

#     key1    key2    key3
# 0  value1  value2  value3
# 1  value4  value5  value6
```

Comment: Thanks but it generates duplicates, many as there is rows and columns...